# Access HttpServletResponse from GWT Client

Tags: java, servlets, gwt, file-upload, httpresponse

I have an upload form to upload a file. The uploading is through `form.submit()` and a `Servlet`. I got a feedback from the server as sesponse and I would like to print the response on GWT-Client to the user. In a servlet I can not use any GUI-Widget so how can I access the http servlet response from gwt client, which invoked the servlet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `HttpServletResponse` class is a server side class, you can't access it from the client side.

What you can do is add a [`FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler.html) to the [`FormPanel`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html), and in the [`onSubmitComplete()`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler.html#onSubmitComplete(com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FormPanel.SubmitCompleteEvent)) method you can access the result text of the form submission:

```
form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {
    public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
        Window.alert(event.getResults());
    }
});
```

Complete runnable example program can be found in the javadoc of [`FileUpload`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FileUpload.html).